# jsPDF ISSUE - image rendering

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I am using **jsPDF library** to generate a MRI report with 4 images. Every time a request submitted to a server, these images are saved to a specified directory and **they are changing** with each request.

when rendering them from the directory to the report, the images from the first request is rendered not the new ones.
**Is there a type of caching in jsPDF ?**

```
generateMRIReport(patientNumber){
    window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;
    const MRI_REPORT = new jsPDF();
     MRI_REPORT.addImage(`WEB-INF/media/testing_mods_${patientNumber}.png`, 'PNG', 5, 80, 196, 70);
     MRI_REPORT.addImage(`WEB-INF/media/testing_preds.png_${patientNumber}.png`, 'PNG', 5, 160, 196, 70);
     MRI_REPORT.save(`NEUROPH_${patientNumber}_MRI_REPORT.pdf`);
}
```

Comment: I've searched for any caching causes through the documentation but, i didn't find any solution

Comment: Looks like your using this in a browser, you might find it's your web server caching the images,.  Look in your network tab to confirm.

Comment: I am using a flask server and the response images which are saved to the specified directory are changing with every new request. (i have checked them on both the server and the directory)

Comment: So what does the Network requests look like, makes no difference if the files have changed on the server side, if Flask is putting out cached headers.  In your browser open up the network tab, the Size column will tell you if it's used cache or not..

Comment: I will figure out if the flask is caching the headers or not and I hope that this causes the problem. Thanks a lot @Keith for your support

Comment: The problem was in caching headers in flask, 
Thanks a lot @keith